# How to handle umlaute like Ä Ö Ü in Coldfusion SQL query to insert into database?

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to insert a string into my database with Coldfusion. However it contains umlauts like `Ä`, `Ö` and `Ü` (German). The umlauts are displayed different than they should in the database. For example I want to insert the value `Eingefügt` but in the Oracle Database it is `EingefÃ¼gt`.

Comment: What is the character set of the database and are you storing it as `VARCHAR2`/`CHAR` data types or `NVARCHAR2`/`NCHAR` data types?

Comment: I am storing it as a varchar2. The character set is WE8MSWIN1252

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `NLS_LANG` settings in both the database and the client - odds are that either of the 2 (or both) are not configured to work with non-english characters.

`select * from v$nls_parameters;` is the command to do the db-level check

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I checked them and recognized that both sides had different settings. Now with both having the same setting it works.

Comment: @FlowLess10 What changes did you modify?

Comment: @Bernhard Döbler I changed the encoding in my editor to the same charset, which is in my database. In my case it is database: WE8MSWIN1252 and visual studio code: Windows 1252. Before i had UTF-8 in the editor, but it can not handle umlauts like Ä,Ö,Ü. So the charset from the datababase was ok to work with umlauts but the editor was not.